# Area of a regular octagon with a side-length of 10 km

Tags: geometry

I am asked to calculate the area of a regular octagon given the side-length of 10 km.

I saw some examples saying that I should start by splitting the octagon into eight isosceles triangles, and that the length of the base would be 10 km, since we're given that the sides of the octagon are all 10km.  What I don't know is what to do next.

Comment: Can you find the angles of the isosceles triangles? If you know one side and all three angles of a triangle, do you know how to compute its area?

Comment: For your first question, if I can, I do not know how.

Second, no I do not.

Comment: Draw a picture if it helps. Put a dot in the center of the regular octagon and draw edges connecting the vertices on the octagon to the dot in the center of the octagon. Notice that you have 8 isosceles triangles inside the regular octagon. I forget the correct terminology but the inner  angle should be 360 degrees divided by 8. Use this to find the other angles.

Comment: Are you supposed to come up with an exact algebraic expression, or can you use trigonometry?

Comment: I'm allowed to use whatever is at my disposal to find the area.

Comment: I appreciate the help, everyone, I really do.  But I just don't understand this.  I'll see if I can get my extremely fast, reluctant teacher to show me what to do tomorrow.

Comment: @Dustin: If you're willing to listen to your "extremely fast" teacher but not to anyone who answers you here (Brian's answer is wonderful), then why did you ask here in the first place?

Comment: Would a 10km side length make the octagon large enough that the curvature of the earth had a non-negligible effect on the area?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I wasn't initially willing to listen to her, I am willing to listen to people who answer me here, but I am not understanding any of the examples provided here.  

In fact, after I talked to her today, I still don't understand it.  Luckily, I took the test and there weren't any octagons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that a different approach is easier: try cutting it up as in the rough sketch below. Once you work out the lengths of the legs of the right triangles, you should be able to calculate the area pretty easily.
[image]

Comment: Well, I would love to do that, but I do not know how.

Comment: @Dustin: Can you see that the triangles are isosceles right triangles, with two angles of $45$°? If $x$ is the length of one of the short sides, the Pythagorean theorem tells you that $2x^2=10$. From that you can calculate the areas of the triangles and rectangles, and the square in the centre clearly has area $10^2=100$.

Comment: @Brian, this is very clever! Dustin, keep in mind that you are now working with 4 isosceles triangles ("move" two of them together to get a square), 4 rectangles, and 1 square. Repeatedly use the length of the edge of the regular octagon to find the area of each of the smaller pieces.

Comment: Thank you, but I am done dicking around with this.  I don't understand this, so I'll try and see if my teacher, who won't slow down for anyone, will tell me what to do.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to suggest an alternate strategy.  A regular octagon has angles of 135$^o$.  I don't know if it's true where you're from, but in the US, stop signs are octagon shaped.  So picture a stop sign, or look at the drawing in Brian's answer.  Now extend the top, bottom, left, and right sides until they meet to form a square with a 45-45-90 right triangle at each corner.  The hypoteneuse of each triangle is a side of the octagon.

Can you finish it from here, calculating the area of the square and subtracting the area of the 4 triangles?

Answer (score 2):

The following trigonometric approach is less elegant (and somewhat harder) than the ones that have been suggested. Its main advantage is that something like it works for any regular polygon.

Let $P$ be the point at the centre of the octagon. Join $P$ to all the vertices. We have divided the octagon into $8$ triangles. Now we find the area of one of these triangles, and multiply by $8$.

Let $PAB$ be one of our $8$ triangles. Draw a perpendicular from $P$ to $AB$. Suppose that this perpendicular meets $AB$ at $Q$. Then the area of $\triangle PAB$ is $\frac{1}{2}(AB)(PQ)$.  We know that $AB=10$, and we need to find $PQ$.

Angle $APQ$ is $360^\circ/8$, that is, $45^\circ$. So the two equal angles  $PAQ$ and $PBQ$ add up to $180^\circ-45^\circ$, that is, $135^\circ$. So each of them is $67.5^\circ$.

Note that
$$\frac{PQ}{AQ}=\tan(\angle PAQ)=\tan(67.5^\circ).$$
But $AQ=5$, and therefore
$$PQ=5\tan(67.5^\circ).$$
So the area of $\triangle PAB$ is $\frac{1}{2}(10)(5\tan(67.5^\circ))$. Multiply by $8$, and simplify. We get that the octagon has area $200\tan(67.5^\circ))$. If you want a decimal approximation, the calculator will give you one.

Answer (score 0):

Area of a $n$-sided regular polygon, $$A=\frac{na^2\cot(\pi/n)}{4}$$ where $a$ is the side length. For your case, $n=8$ and $a=10$ which gives $A=200\cot(\pi/8) km^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Use The equation :

```
A = .5asn
```

This works with all regular polygons.

a is the length of the apothem(Perpendicular bisector of one side to the center point of the polygon)

s is the length of each side

n is the number of sides

This is really is splitting the polygon into triangles where the apothem is the height of said triangle and each side of the polygon is the base of that triangle. n is just the number of sides/number of triangles